# How to solve e Py4JJavaError:py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o331.csv

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am studing on PySpark Python and i get an error.

When the code uses df.show() and df.toJson(), there is no error, But when writing to csv, will get an error.

this is piece of Code

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').option("compression", "gzip").json(file_name)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks!

I tried to print all the information to copy to a json file, json file format without errors,

```
for i in df.collect():
  print(i)
```

```
Row(host='simple', dir_='/temp/1/_pageSize', key='Number', max_size=80, min_size=10, type_info=['Z'])
...
```

below  with detail error.

````
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:526)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ResultStage 31 (json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 13    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:867)    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:863)    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)   at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:863)    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:677)  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:49)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ShuffledRowRDD.compute(ShuffledRowRDD.scala:165)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(CoalescedRDD.scala:100)   at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(CoalescedRDD.scala:99)    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:380)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1368)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1817)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`df=df.limit(df.count()+1)`

I found a strange solution, When I tested which line of data was in trouble，

Try to use  ,no error.

```
for i in range(100,df.count()+100,100):
    df1=df.limit(i)
    df1.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').option("compression", "gzip").json(file_name)
```

But didn't understand why it was causing the problem.

When this code is added, it is write normally, if it is not, the above error appears

spark:2.3
python:3.5.9